# Start Windows Service remotely access

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to start and stop a windows service on server1 from a deployed asp.net application on server2.

I'm using the following code to start it but an "Access denied" exception is thrown because I'm a non-admin user:

```
string serviceName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ServiceName"];
string machineName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MachineName"];

System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController service = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(serviceName, machineName);

if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
    return Json("Service is running.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
service.Start();
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);

if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
    return Json("Service started successfully.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
else
{
    return Json("Could not start the service.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Can anyone help me, please ?

Comment: I think the problem is that you do not have appropriate permissions to do this. I also think you already know that, since I figured it out by reading the question. So what are you actually asking here?

Comment: First you need to figure out what account it is.  Since you're running in an asp.net app - it might not be the end user's creds - it might be the apppool's identity.  It all depends on the aspnet config (delegation etc...)

Comment: Search on asp.net impersonation delegation configuration

Comment: I dont know how to configure it , i know that the problem is due to privileges but how to set it ? in the code or in iis ?

Comment: i used the **Service Security Editor** to allow remotly service control. [link](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceSecurityEditor)

Answer (score 2):

to control windows service remotly we need administrator rights so i only edited the permissions for my windows service using **Service Security Editor** .http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceSecurityEditor it may help you.